# Sorting records in a way so that only records which matches an id comes first?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a query which return me the records or messages for a certain scenario:

```
const [messages, messageCount] = await Promise.all([
    MessageModel.find(params).select(filterObject).limit(ctx.query.limit).skip(ctx.paginate.skip)
      .sort('-sex -age')
      .lean(),
    MessageModel.countDocuments(params),
  ]);
```

Is there any way to get the records first which matches an object id, and then rest of the records?

Result

```
{
_id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
isPrivate:false
message:"My name is stark"
gender:"unisex"
age: "19"
createdBy:abcff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
}
{
_id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
isPrivate:false
message:"My name is james"
gender:"unisex"
age: "20"
createdBy:defff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
}
{
_id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
isPrivate:false
message:"My name is harry"
gender:"unisex"
age: "20"
createdBy:defff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
}
{
_id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
isPrivate:false
message:"My name is max"
gender:"unisex"
age: "20"
createdBy:abcff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
}
```

Now I want those messages that was created by the abc... first. All those records that match a certain id would come first and then rest of the records would remain the same

```
{
_id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
isPrivate:false
message:"My name is stark"
gender:"unisex"
age: "19"
createdBy:abcff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
}

{
    _id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
    isPrivate:false
    message:"My name is max"
    gender:"unisex"
    age: "20"
    createdBy:abcff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
    }
    {
    _id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
    isPrivate:false
    message:"My name is james"
    gender:"unisex"
    age: "20"
    createdBy:defff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
    }
    {
    _id:abc0aa8573bfa917b152cdbc
    isPrivate:false
    message:"My name is harry"
    gender:"unisex"
    age: "20"
    createdBy:defff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what is your match condition `params`? provide more details about current output and expected result as per your document and input match condition.

Comment: Params usually contains filters and two id, the user id and the workbase id. I usually get all the messages by this. What I want now, I want to get all the messages related to certain user id first, and then the rest of the messages

Comment: @turivishal I added some dummy data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any straight way to do this, If you really want to then try `$cond` operator to check condition on specific field,

- add new field `matchResult` in `$project` it will check `createdBy` is matching return 1 otherwise 0,
- `$sort` by `matchResult` in descending order

```
const [messages, messageCount] = await Promise.all([
    MessageModel.aggregate([
        { $match: params },
        {
            $project: {
                ...filterObject,
                matchResult: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: ["$createdBy", ObjectId("abcff9ef71fa048cea3c8a97")] },
                      1,
                      0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        { $sort: { matchResult: -1 } },
        { $skip: ctx.paginate.skip },
        { $limit: ctx.query.limit }
    ]),
    MessageModel.countDocuments(params),
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A9tIAh2ppw_)

---

Second option is [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html) aggregation operator starting from MongoDB v4.2,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HPSZBB1WSVz)

> I am not recommending this approach for big data in collection, this may cause performance issue, it is better to sort in your client side after query.

Comment: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use expression other than $meta in exclusion projection. :(

Comment: might be the issue in `filterObject` is it object? just pass it as an object, look at the playground i have added in answer

Comment: Why is it better to sort on the client side instead doing it on the server end with aggregation? Do we have any articles regarding the impact of having an aggregation pipeline with certain operators?

Comment: This kind of operations may cause performance issues, 
Because we are generating field in query and doing operations on it, 
it will never use index see [Optimize Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/)
How to optimize our query see [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) and [Aggregation Pepeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/),

Comment: if you really want to learn something mongodb i would suggest you to try mongodb [free courses](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/catalog) from mongodb university