# How We combine two query in MongoDB $in and $nin with same condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to combine the result of `$in` query with `$nin` query and want the final result. So how we can do this using one mongo query? is there is any way to do it?
For e.g., I have the following documents in the user collection:

```
[{
    name:"test",
    "uid":123
},{
    name:"test1",
    "uid":124
},{
    name:"test2",
    "uid":125
},{
    name:"test3",
    "uid":126
},{
    name:"test3",
    "uid":127
}]
```

and I want the following result:

```
[{
    name:"test2",
    "uid":125
},{
    name:"test3",
    "uid":126
},{
    name:"test",
    "uid":123
},{
    name:"test3",
    "uid":127
}]
```

Basically I want `uid:125` and `uid:126` on first two position ignore about their sequence and then `uid:123` and `uid: 127` on 3rd and 4th position ignore about their sequence. So I am doing this by following two query

1. `db.getCollection('user').find({uid:{$in:[125,126]}})`
2. `db.getCollection('user').find({uid:{$nin:[125,126]}})`

and then I am combining the result but How I can do this in the same query? I have so many documents it is just example so need to combine the result of $in and $nin query

How I can do this?

Comment: can you provide more details, current result, expected result and your query implementation and sample document.

Comment: @turivishal updated the question can you please help to solve this

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to do this, I have recently answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609292/8987128), almost similar question,

- You need to use aggregation query, try `$cond` will check if `uid` in array `[125, 126]` then return 1 otherwise 0 in `matchResult`,
- `$sort` by `matchResult` in descending order

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchResult: {
        $cond: [{ $in: ["$uid", [125, 126]] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { matchResult: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q-zGK-nHgfP)